Using Named Columns in Excel VBA instead of Column Numbers
All similar questions reference cells and not entire columns.
I would like to use Column (not cell) Names instead of Letters for my macros so that inserting or deleting columns won't become an issue.
This currently works for an auto-selection macro;
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 4 To LastRow
    If Cells(i, 12).Value <> "ZZZZZZZZZ" Or Cells(i, 12).Value <> "ZZZZZZZZY" Then
        If Cells(i, 36).Value = "Y" Then
            If Cells(i, 11) = "" Then
                Range("K" & i).Value = "a"
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next i

Using the Name Manager, I've named the Entire Column accordingly;

#11,$K = Invited
#12,$L = CompanyName
#36,$AK = Select01

If I change it to the following, it doesn't work or recognize the names so I'm not sure the appropriate way to address it in this circumstance;
If Cells(i, "CompanyName").Value <> "ZZZZZZZZZ" Or Cells(i, "CompanyName").Value <> "ZZZZZZZZY" Then
        If Cells(i, "Select01").Value = "Y" Then
            If Cells(i, "Invited") = "" Then
                Range("Invited" & i).Value = "a"

Thank you for your help!

The 2nd argument of Cells is either the column index or column letter. Use Range to refer to named ranges. If your name refers to a single cell, but you need to loop over multiple cells in that column, then use Cells(i, Range("CompanyName").Column)

LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count ... this is unreliable. See this.

Thank you and that works but doesn't resolve the Range("K" & i).Value = "a".  I substituted in Invited for K but that causes an error.

Range("Invited" & i) would only work if you create a named range such as Invited4, Invited5, etc. Perhaps you want Cells(i, Range("Invited").Column).Value = "a".

You could use the shorter and more readable Range("Invited")(i).Value = "a" where (i) is short for .Cells(i).
